# Storing Last Reading in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Hello I am trying to write a sketch that reads the distance from an ultrasonic distance sensor and only sends the data if the previous and current readings are to different (20cm). Below is my sketch;

```
const int TRIG_PIN = 12;
const int ECHO_PIN = 11;

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); // RX | TX
// Anything over 400 cm (23200 us pulse) is "out of range"
const unsigned int MAX_DIST = 23200;

void setup() {

  // The Trigger pin will tell the sensor to range find
  pinMode(TRIG_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);

  // We'll use the serial monitor to view the sensor output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTserial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {

  unsigned long t1;
  unsigned long t2;
  unsigned long pulse_width;
  float cm;
  float inches;
  float lastcm;
  float diff;

  // Hold the trigger pin high for at least 10 us
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIG_PIN, LOW);

  // Wait for pulse on echo pin
  while ( digitalRead(ECHO_PIN) == 0 );

  // Measure how long the echo pin was held high (pulse width)
  // Note: the () microscounter will overflow after ~70 min
  t1 = micros();
  while ( digitalRead(ECHO_PIN) == 1);
  t2 = micros();
  pulse_width = t2 - t1;

  // Calculate distance in centimeters and inches. The constants
  // are found in the datasheet, and calculated from the assumed speed 
  //of sound in air at sea level (~340 m/s).
  cm = pulse_width / 58.0;
  diff = cm - lastcm;
  lastcm = cm;

  // Print out results
  if ( pulse_width > MAX_DIST ) {
    BTserial.write("Out of range");
    lastcm = cm;
  } else {
    Serial.println(diff);
    Serial.println("Or act value");
    Serial.println(cm);
    lastcm = cm;
    if (abs(diff)>20) {
      BTserial.println(cm);
      }


  }

  // Wait at least 60ms before next measurement
  delay(150);
}
```

However this is not correctly calculating the difference between the two values - as the serial monitor just returns

```
29.24
Or act value
29.24
29.31
Or act value
29.31
28.83
Or act value
28.83
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What sensor are you using? If it's the HC-SR04 (which I think it is from the code), your problem is that you don't want the pulse width. You want the time from sending the pulse to the echo pin going high (when you receive it). Even if you're using a different sensor, any sensor that makes you send your own pulse is probably not going to give you an output with the distance as a pulse duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable 'lastcm' is declared inside the loop function. You have two options. Either declare it external to the loop or else declare it where you do but make it static (in either case you also have to deal with the initial invalid reading that it contains)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this sketch and make it less prone to error by using the NewPing library:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing